# How to work with more than 1 buttons in kivy GridLayout? [ closed ]

Tags: python, button, kivy

i am learning kivy layout : grid layout and i create a couple of buttons on it in .kv file

```
<Grid_Layout>:

    GridLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        rows: 3
        cols: 3

        Button:
            text: "Top Left"
            on_touch_up: print("HI")

        Button:
            text: "Top Center"

        Button:
            text: "Top Right"

        Button:
            text: "Center Left"

        Button:
            text: "Center Center"

        Button:
            text: "Center Right"

        Button:
            text: "Bottom Left"

        Button:
            text: "Bottom Center"

        Button:
            text: "Bottom Right"
```

want to ask :

- if I don't add the `size: root.width, root.height` the whole layout will shrink together , is there any solution ?
- like one specific button is pressed , it do stuff and they are not identical. i tried `on_touch_up: print("HI")` but it printed the 'HI' no matter which button i pressed lol but i don't want this : ( so want to ask is there any solutions ? : )

thx : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the definition of your `Grid_Layout` class, which is likely the key to why your layout changes size.

To use the `Button`, you should define `on_press` or `on_release` instead of `on_touch_up`,  like this:

```
    Button:
        text: "Top Left"
        on_release: print("HI")
```

If your `Grid_Layout` class is defined as:

```
class Grid_Layout(GridLayout):
    pass
```

then your `Grid_Layout` class is a `GridLayout`, so you don't need to add another `GridLayout` inside it. That is effectively creating a `GridLayout` inside a `GridLayout`, which is OK if that is what you intended, but not necessary in your posted code. Your `kv` can be something like this:

```
<Grid_Layout>:
    rows: 3
    cols: 3

    Button:
        text: "Top Left"
        on_release: print("HI")

    Button:
        text: "Top Center"
.
.
.
```

And the

```
size: root.width, root.height
```

is not needed.

Comment: like i have to add ```def Grid_Layout(GridLayout):
    pass
```
in the .py file ?

Comment: oh i just added `class Grid_Layout(GridLayout):    pass` in .py file and cancel out the `GridLayout:` in .kv file and it works : )  lol thanks for helping

Comment: oic ~ i get it : )